# Visual Workflow - Creating Paragraphs and Double Line Breaks

Tags: visual-workflow, html

For whatever reason, when I try to create double line breaks using the Visual Workflow HTML editor the 2nd gets removed

Tried doing this by just using "Enter" key and editing the actual HTML by adding

tags or  tag. Each time these appear to work in the editor but when I run sometimes works sometimes doesn't.

Eventually it removes all of the tags entered and reverts back to single spacing.

Ex/
Line1
Line2

Should be:
Line1

Line2

**Edited to add:**
I put a little of the code below generated by Flow. It strips out `<br>` tags.

```
  <SPAN ALIGN="LEFT">

  <FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size:12px" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">

  </FONT>

  </SPAN>

  <DIV ALIGN="LEFT">

  <FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size:12px" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">

  Select the Month Days and Times for {!vaprovidername}.

  </FONT>

  </DIV>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Workflow: I was having the same problem and created a Constant called BlankDisplayLine and gave it the value `<br></br>` (i didn't put " around this to be clear that i didn't use "s in the value).
Then, in the Display Text, i added {!BlankDisplayLine} to the text.
That was the only way i could solve this (kind of stupid) problem.

Answer (score 2):

A VF page expects you to close any HTML tags. You may be getting a single line break by pressing the enter key because you're closing an open tag and its creating either a line break or padding around the block you've just closed. In the latter case, you may need to follow the closed tag by a single line break.

The proper code to use for a double line break would be as follows:

```
<br></br> \\ 1st line break
<br></br> \\ 2nd line break
```

If the above doesn't work, then please post your code so we'll have something to view and help you debug your problem.

**BEGIN EDIT**

First, I want to point out that I made typos in my original code. I had typed `<br><\br>` instead of what's now correctly typed above, which may be why yours got stripped out by Flow; esp if you did a copy paste. Note: SF requires `<BR>` tags to be closed with a `</BR>` or else will remove them!

That said, based on the code you supplied, I'd add the tags in the location as shown below. They need to be nested so they fall within the `<DIV>` tags:

```
<DIV ALIGN="LEFT">

<FONT FACE="Arial" STYLE="font-size:12px" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">

Select the Month Days and Times for {!vaprovidername}.

<br></br> \\ 1st line break

<br></br> \\ 2nd line break

</FONT>

</DIV>
```

I should also add that the LETTERSPACING = "0" and KERNING ="0" tags aren't necessary **UNLESS** you specified different values in the HTML that appeared above this section.